# Finding minimum height of a binary tree

Tags: recursion, height, binary-tree

Please read my question before you report it as a duplicate. In the literature, to find the minimum height of a tree, the common approach is as follow:

```
int minDepth(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) { return 0;}
        return 1 + Math.min(minDepth(root.left), minDepth(root.right));
}
```

However, I think it does not distinguish between a leaf and a node with only one child and so it returns a wrong value. For example if our tree looks like this:

A is root

B is the left child of A

C is the right child of B

M is the left child of C

This function returns one while the leaf is 3 hop away from the root and so the min height is 4.

Since this recursive version is generally suggested in the literature, I think I am missing something.

Could somebody clear this for me?

Comment: I guess “the literature” uses a definition of binary tree where each non-leaf node has exactly two children then. By the way, I think your example can be shortened to the two nodes A and B.

Comment: In a binary tree a node has 0, one or two children. For that definition, I see this recursive function for the minHeight.

Comment: Then what is the definition of “minimal height“?

Comment: The shortest distance(path) between the root and a leaf in a tree.

Comment: With what I know as the definition of “leaf,” that is wrong then, yes.

Comment: Are you familiar with the "Cracking the coding Interview"? This algorithm is also suggested there at page 123 although I can not understand why it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments indicate that the texts where you found this actually use the same definitions for the terms I use. If that is indeed the case, then the question is not why the algorithm you have shown is correct – it simply is wrong under those conditions.

Just take the third simplest binary tree, the one consisting of two nodes. It has exactly one leaf, its depth is two and its minimal depth is also two. But the algorithm you quoted returns the value one. So, unless the authors use a different definition for one of the terms (e.g., “minimal height” meaning “shortest path out of the tree”/“shortest path to a null pointer”), the result is simply wrong.

Comment: Can somebody please show me the algorithm which will return 4 instead of 1...if the input given to a binary tree is as follows: 100, 50, 70, 60 ??